# Reducing the number of lines in the code with named scope in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

i have rails method to sort the blogs based on their votes (acts_as_votable).

The method is

```
      # @allblogs will be some filtered blogs array
      @fetch = []
      @most_effective_votes = []
      for blog in @allblogs
        @most_effective_votes << [blog.id,blog.votes_for]
      end
      @most_effective_votes = @most_effective_votes.sort{|a,b| a[1]<=> b[1]}.Reverse
      for mev in @most_effective_votes
        @fetch << blog.Find(mev[0])
      end
      @allblogs = @fetch.Paginate(:per_page => 10,:page=>params[:page])
```

How to reduce these many number of lines and to change this to some namedscope .
Please give some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think must of what you are trying to do can be done with a query without the need of doing operations with arrays.

First of all, @allblogs should be a scope, not a filtered array.

Second, it sames you can change all of what you were doing by using:

```
Blog.order("DESC votes_for")
```

So your named_scope would be:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :with_most_votes, order("votes_for DESC")
end
```

And @fetch would be @allblogs.with_most_votes.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: No i have to use the allblogs only and not Blog.all . As allblogs are from some other function returned value. I tried with scope which didnt worked throwing Argument error. I tried with allblogs.find(:all,:include => ["votes"],:conditions => ["votes.voteable_type = 'Blog' and votes.voteable_id = blogs.id and vote =?",true],:group => ["votes.voteable_id"],:order => ["count(votes.id) desc"]) which is working in console. and throwing argument error in server side. why so ?

Comment: You can't apply a scope to an array. Can you show me the function that returns allblogs?